# How to know where to use mb_string and where not?

Tags: php

I have a script, how to know if the string is **multibyte** or not?

Is it safe to always use `mb_string` functions?

Isn't it slower? Does it work as fast as normal string functions on considering it is not multibyte string?

Comment: So, do you make it a habit of posting questions, getting solutions and then run off not doing anything about them, as in "accepting" their answer?

Comment: Did you run a benchmark?? Did you research this??

Answer (score 0):

> **I'm have a script, how to know if string is multybyte or not?**

Detect character encoding **mb_detect_encoding**

```
 string mb_detect_encoding ( string $str [, mixed $encoding_list =
 mb_detect_order() [, bool $strict = false ]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

> **Is it safe to always use mb_string functions?**

Exploit : **heap buffer overflow**

Due to the decoder's incorrect handling of error conditions, the bounds check for a heap-allocated buffer is effectively bypassed. An attacker can exploit this vulnerability to transfer arbitrary data to a specific region of the heap if he gains control over the input of the decoder.

> Solution:
>   Upgrade to version 5.2.8. Note that the maintenance of 4.x series was discontinued.

http://www.securiteam.com/unixfocus/6X00P0ANFM.html

> **Isn't it slower? Does it work as fast as normal string functions on**
>   **considering it is not multibyte string?**

**Iconv vs mbstring solution**

https://beeznest.wordpress.com/2008/10/05/mbstring-vs-iconv-benchmarking/

Comment: I was asking how do I know if it's multibyte, not how I reckognize encoding. Also english.

Comment: @J. Does I Still reading the question but isn't clear about how languages recognition you do with multibyte. Isn't simple to comment but take a look at this project on github you got a solution just take a time to install and test i got a prefered method named `bestResults()`. Regards. https://github.com/headmax/language-detection

Comment: @J. Doe Oh i see sorry you got a class was writed in the phpcake framework named checkMultibytes https://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Multibyte.html but didn't tested i dunno if there is a vendor or a bundle to installed in you projects. https://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-Multibyte.html#861-877

Comment: I need to manualy look at it, I just can't parse string twice once to reckognize if it's multybyte and once to parse it normaly, it would be slow down isntead of using one mb_string parse, I will deal with gigs of strings daily.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use mb* methods if you expect characters that are not described in the ASCII table (English & Spanish langs). Also you shouldn't use $string[n] calls to get chars from the string in this case.
2. mb* methods are usually ~x1.5 times slower than non-mb* methods. However it doesn't make any real sense for common web tasks.
3. Please don't use mb_detect_encoding to detect charset. It may work really inaccurate because such methods use algos that are based on guessing about chars in the stream and it's statistics. The best solution here is to say that all parts of your code will work only with 1 predefined charset (just select UTF-8 or any other charset and use only it for all your internal tasks with strings). There are only few exceptions from this simple rule (file editors and some cross-platform document-based applications).